# how to read the FS(File Speartor) in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88G3.png)

**In C# how to read the text file (File Sperator)FS**

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
// Or the encoding of the file
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

// where somefile.txt is your file
string text = File.ReadAllText("somefile.txt", encoding);

// the splitted parts. FS is the \x1C hex character.
string[] parts = text.Split('\x1C');
```